# TYPO3 - Personalize content of the box in backend

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I've built a new content element type, and when you look in the backend, inside the box you can see the name of the module only. I'd like to change what information is show inside.

I could use the "header" field, but is there any way to use another field(s)?

[image: Example module]

Comment: Sorry, with domains being in lowercase and after years of fighting people on chats, begging not to  write everything with Caps, it gets counter-intuitive :D

Comment: @biessior: Pls is also unpolite.

Comment: @biessior: Yes, and I was his first security team leader when I get dismissed.

Comment: @biesior: I don't know what you mean? Both is possible?

Comment: @Chiyou I mean that I'm glad that I met a security guy. About TYPO3 vs Typo3 - I'm correcting still and still questions and answers in the Stack Overflow - and I'm just impatient when long-term TYPO3 users still repeats the same mistake, is that wrong ?

Comment: @Chiyou And as usually I've just deleted 'non constructive' comments :) to keep question clear.

Comment: I do not get your question. You are showing a part of a screenshot of the page module and at the same time your are asking questions about backend modules and content elements? What is your problem and what are you trying to do?

Comment: You seen inside the content element says "Default Staff Member". Usually under that appears what you write in the "header" field. I'd like to be able to change it, for what is shown in other fields.

Comment: So you have built a new content element type?

Comment: Yes; I have done exactly that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two answers

### First answer

The field that's displayed there is the same field that's displayed in the list module. It is set in the table's TCA using ['ctrl']['label'] in the extension's `ext_tables.php`

```
$TCA['tx_myext_mytable'] = array(   
        'ctrl' => array(
        'title' => 'My Table'
        'label' => 'name_of_the_field_to_display_as_header' 
// end snip
```

### Second answer

If that is not enough for you, you can use a hook to display arbitrary HTML in the preview. The hook is called `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['cms/layout/class.tx_cms_layout.php']['tt_content_drawItem']`.

The hook will be called with a function with this signature:

```
public function preProcess(
    tx_cms_layout &$parentObject,  // parent object
    &$drawItem,   // i have no idea what this is
    &$headerContent,  /* the content of the header
                         (the grey bar in the screenshot i think) */
    &$itemContent,  /* the content of the preview
                       (the white area in your screenshot */
    array &$row // the content element's record
)
```

So all you have to do in that function is set the itemContent and, if you want, headerContent to whatever you want displayed.

Gotchas:

1. The output is inside of a span, so no block elements allowed in the
   html. Any styling has to be done inline in the style attribute.
2. The function will be called on *every* content element, so you have to
   check the row's `CType` and (if applicable) `list_type` fields so
   that you only manipulate your own content elements.

An example can be found in the "fed" extension. I hope this helps.

Comment: With the first answer, I wouldnt be able to put any kind of html, like for instance images, right? Only text?

Comment: Well, you set the name of the column in the table that's displayed as the preview in the backend. For each record, it displays the value of that column. I am almost sure that HTML is stripped. It wouldn't be a good idea, anyway, because that same setting is also used for the list view.

I'll see if I can expand a bit on the second option.

Comment: Expanded. I hope this gives you a better idea.

Comment: Addendum: If you created a new content element type (so it's in the tt_content-table), my first answer is a no-go, as you can only switch the label field by table, not by content element type. So you will have to use the second option.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little update to adhominem answear #2 which is correct.

Today in TYPO3 6.2 and above your hook class has to inherit the interface `TYPO3\CMS\Backend\View\PageLayoutViewDrawItemHookInterface`

It´s looks like belove

```
<?php
namespace TYPO3\CMS\Backend\View;

/**
 * Interface for classes which hook into PageLayoutView and do additional
 * tt_content_drawItem processing.
 *
 * @author Oliver Hader <oliver@typo3.org>
 */
interface PageLayoutViewDrawItemHookInterface {

    /**
     * Preprocesses the preview rendering of a content element.
     *
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Backend\View\PageLayoutView $parentObject Calling parent object
     * @param boolean $drawItem Whether to draw the item using the default functionalities
     * @param string $headerContent Header content
     * @param string $itemContent Item content
     * @param array $row Record row of tt_content
     * @return void
     */
    public function preProcess(\TYPO3\CMS\Backend\View\PageLayoutView &$parentObject, &$drawItem, &$headerContent, &$itemContent, array &$row);

}
```

`&$drawItem` is boolean and send as reference and by changing it to `$drawItem = false;` will stop the default rendering of the preview.